# Johansen Cointegration Test - Interpret results to find Behavioral Equilibrium Exchange Rate

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I need help understanding the results of Johansen cointegration test in detail. I found the results of a test performed in Zhang, Zhibai (2010), and would like to know where these values come from, as I need this for further analysis.

```
Table 3
RMB misalignments influenced by different econometric component choices
Variables change Observations change Estimations change
            Case 1      Case 2      Case 3      Case 4      Case 5      Case 7
Variables   Three       Four        Five        Four        Four        Four
Observations 1952-2004  1952-2004   1952-2004   1962-2004   1952-1994   1952-2004  

Estimations Johansen    Johansen    Johansen    Johansen    Johansen    EG  
1962        0.195       0.164       0.055       0.277       0.026       0.127  
1963        0.148       0.117       0.022       0.218       -0.008      0.073  
1964        0.170       0.135       0.055       0.226       0.025       0.070  
1965        0.197       0.158       0.093       0.238       0.063       0.060  
1966        0.170       0.126       0.077       0.196       0.045       -0.012
```

These are the results of Johansen test I obtained.

```
Test type: maximal eigenvalue statistic (lambda max) , without linear trend and constant in cointegration

Eigenvalues (lambda):
[1]  6.629064e-01  5.673531e-01  4.423277e-01  3.493767e-01  7.347698e-02
[6] -9.714451e-17
Values of teststatistic and critical values of test:

         test  10pct 5pct  1pct  

r <= 4 | 2.90  7.52  9.24  12.97   
r <= 3 | 16.33 13.75 15.67 20.20   
r <= 2 | 22.19 19.77 22.00 26.81   
r <= 1 | 31.84 25.56 28.14 33.24   
r = 0  | 41.32 31.66 34.40 39.79
```

Please guide me how to arrive at the values shown in the paper.